# Wrapped, vertically scrolling alphabet in libGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, alphabetical

I need a vertically scrolling alphabet in libGDX.  The user won't directly interact with it. I thought about using ScrollPane, however, it doesn't seem to wrap (I'm happy to be corrected if I have that wrong).

I plan to present five letters at a time.  The vertically scrolling alphabet needs to wrap so that when the bottom letter is 'Z' and it scrolls upwards, 'A' becomes the bottom letter.

What's the best approach for this in libGDX?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

VerticalGroup has an option to wrap the content.

```
VerticalGroup group = new VerticalGroup();
group.wrap();
group.addActor( ... ); // a table or the individual letters

ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane( group );
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's probably what I need.  Much apprecaited!